# Custom cursor placing when using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

This is not about new macros like `\newcommand`, `\def` and others.

This is not about autocompletion like using `.cwl` (in TexStudio)

This is also not about using shortcuts for predefined commands that are listed in the shortcuts sections.

None of the questions I could find here have answered this. I want to make a macro in TexStudio for various kinds of mathematics, but when I execute them I want **to choose where the cursor goes.**

For example, I know how to make a macro that would give me two modulus signs, so that when hitting ctrl + F2 (or the like) I get:

```
| |
```

Woopee, but now the cursor is to the right, and not actually **in between** the modulus signs.

( For an example of what I want to do, when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>, such a command is executed, you get

```
$ $
```

With the cursor ready to insert the math inbetween. )

Do you guys reckon it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see section 4.5.1 in Help --> User manual.

Specifically, the string `%|` in a macro decides where the cursor ends up, so if you go to Macros --> Edit macros, and make a new one where the *LaTeX content* is

```
|%||
```

then when hitting the corresponding shortcut, you will get two pipes with the cursor between them.

Comment: Perfect, you've just made my TeXing 1% faster :) :)